# Change a hashed password on PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, hash, phpmyadmin, salt

I want to change the password of an account through PHPMyAdmin, but the passwords are all encrypted. I get an error when trying to change the password of the account through the applicaiton so I will do it here instead if possible.

Here is the code for the password:

```
$salt = $this->create_salt_password($username);
                $hash = $salt . $password;
                for ( $i = 0; $i < 100000; $i ++ ) 
                {
                    $hash = hash('sha256', $hash);
                }
                $hash = $salt . $hash;
```

And:

```
define('AUTH_SALT','wcRwGxDzULe?s3J%R^W@9)r}xfXpESul5hC,z^ze.oz*1E|ys,Bk,:Q/z_I&M9..');
```

I am trying to use sha1-online.com to first of all re-create the hash which is stored on the database at the moment.

The password is stored as:

`6b68f3c4d174fa0a8163db9fc9abdd81a75f9186a95c686039acaa4ac1d99f75dd0f838e6eb30412121e228bc4008d446d4ad24b3748beed7a28de3d78999122`

and as a string is just `password123`

salt method:

```
public function create_salt_password($username)
        {
        /** Creates a hash value for the password using 
            a prefixed random unique identifier value with a static characters and the username
        */
            $salt = hash('sha256', uniqid(mt_rand(), true) .AUTH_SALT .strtolower($username));
            return $salt;
        }
```

Comment: I am trying to change the password in PHPMyAdmin as I cannot use the application. I was advised to use the hashing methods to generate the new password hash and store this in the database, so first...I am trying to regenerate password123 on sha1-online with no luck...maybe I am writing it wrong on there

Comment: To change the password in phpadmin, click edit next to the row you want to alter. Copy the new hash and paste in the appropriate place

Comment: So I am trying to get from password123 -> database stored password. Then I can create a new password and store it in the database I think

Comment: @relentless Yes I am trying to do this, but I don't know how to change it to the correct hash. Let's say I want to make the new password just `password`. How would I generate the hash for this based on the PHP code I have given?

Comment: You're missing some key code, for example the create_salt_password() function. Could you add this to your question?

Comment: You should be able to just default the password to `abc123` then go back and change it with your application

Comment: So, go to phpadmin, edit the password and change to `abc123` then update your password via your application and it will salt and hash it for you

Comment: @RMK I have added the code for the function above

Comment: @relentless Yes, but the update password function in the application is not working, so I would like to change it through phpmyadmin, I posted the salt above, so I'm trying to reproduce the hash from password123 somehow so i can simply enter the hash into the password field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will probably (if we're not missing any code) help you recreate a working pass:

```
$username = 'sweetest_viv';
$password = 'password123';
$staticsalt = 'wcRwGxDzULe?s3J%R^W@9)r}xfXpESul5hC,z^ze.oz*1E|ys,Bk,:Q/z_I&M9..';

$salt = hash('sha256', uniqid(mt_rand(), true) .$staticsalt.strtolower($username));

$hash = $salt . $password;
for ( $i = 0; $i < 100000; $i ++ ) 
{
$hash = hash('sha256', $hash);
}
$hash = $salt . $hash;

echo 'Salt: ' . PHP_EOL . $salt;
echo PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
echo 'Hash: ' . PHP_EOL . $hash ;
```

Try storing the hash from http://codepad.org/rBfS6wEJ.

Comment: There is no way to do this externally? I am pretty new to PHP so I don't really know how to execute this to recreate a password or hash  :/ I'm working with a hosted application online, not a local application as I was having trouble with getting SOAP/PHP working on my local PC

Comment: Looking closer into it; this only helps you recreate the salting hash (probably stored separately in your table). You need to get the code that combines/generates the hash for the password.

Comment: The only code I see is that it takes the password from the form...uses the create_salt_password function and then uses this in the code above to generate the hash

Comment: I don't understand because the hash i put in my OP is the hash which is stored in the database as the password? So if I want to change the hash from `password123` to just `password` for example, how would I do that in phpmyadmin? From what I see the hash you have output is not the same as the one stored in the DB

Comment: The hash is dynamic (salting part is created random). Save the current hash and generate a new one, save the hash in de db and try a login. Could work.